# How to send notifications to apple watch without an app for apple watch

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-watch

I wanna send notifications to apple watch but without an app for apple watch.

Our app is a game only for iphone and ipad.
 
So I didn't find any info about this case in developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Apple Watch Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html)

> Apps are not required to do anything to support notifications. The
>   system provides a default notification interface that displays the
>   alert message from the notification. However, apps can customize the
>   notification interface and include custom graphics, content, and
>   branding.

Comment: If I don't develop an apple watch app, how to receive the notifications for iPhone's app?

Comment: They should be automatically forwarded to the watch.

Comment: Thanks@Fogh  I think you are right! Here [link][1] says as long as your Apple Watch is paired with your iPhone over Bluetooth or Wi-Fi, whatever is sent to your iPhone will be relayed to your Apple Watch.                        [1]: (http://www.imore.com/how-set-notifications-your-apple-watch)

Comment: The Apple documentation that I linked to says the same. You should mark my answer as accepted :)